NP-hardness of optimization with promise
Consider the Minimum Bisection problem, which asks, for a given $k$, whether the vertices of a graph can be partitioned into two parts of equal size such that the number of edges between these two parts is at most $k$. Minimum Bisection is known to be NP-hard. Is the version of Minimum Bisection where we are promised that there is no solution of size at most $k-1$ (hence, every solution must have size $k$ or above) also NP-hard?
More generally, is the same true for every computational problem of a similar form (asking whether there is a solution of size at most $k$)?

There are minimization problems where even if you know there are no solutions with value $k-1$, determining if there is a solution of value $k$ is still NP-hard. One is graph colouring, where even if you know a graph is not 2-colourable, it is NP-complete to determine if it is 3-colourable.
In fact, if you have an NP-complete problem where you can easily rule out the existence of a solution of size less than $b$, and $k-b$ is polynomial in in the size of the input, then the problem must still be NP-hard even with the promise that there is no solution of size strictly less than $k$. If there were some polynomial time algorithm, we could just keep applying it, first to $b$ then to $b+1$ and so forth until either one of them returns TRUE, or the question applied to $k$ returns FALSE.
In particular, this means your problem must still be NP-complete. Since you can determine in polynomial time if your graph is connected. If it is, there is no solution of size $0$. If the graph is not connected, you can determine if there is a solution of size $0$ by solving the Partition Problem where the given integers are the sizes of the connected components of your graph. The Partition Problem is NP-complete, but it has a fully polynomial time approximation scheme (FPTAS) and so we can solve it by setting the required error to be "small enough" ($2/n$).
I think it would be difficult to say something about all computation problems asking whether there is a solution of size at most $k$. In particular, I am not sure how you would incorporate the "promise" theoretically. Intuitively we want to say that we are restricting the space of allowed inputs to those satisfying the promise. But, at least under the Turing Machine model of computation, making sure the input actually encodes the kind of input that is expected is work that needs to be done by the Turing Machine.  Hopefully someone with a little more knowledge about complexity theory and the theory of computation can weigh in.
